# How to get specific part of a strings from a string using javascript?

Tags: javascript

I have a RGBA color in this format:

```
RGBA:1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922
```

How can I separate each value from this string such as:

```
var alpha = 1.000000;
var red = 0.003922;
var green = 0.003922;
var blue = 0.003922;
```

I want to do this in javascript.

Comment: `slice` then `split` then `map`

Comment: @Anni - Ive replaced "jQuery" with "javascript" in both the title and question. The reason is that this is not a task that requires jQuery - it's vanilla javascript stuff.

Comment: Or a little more specifically: `str.slice(5).split(',').map(Number)`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no need to use jQuery. It is rather straightforward JavaScript operation. The easiest way is to use [`String.prototype.split()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/split) method:

```
var rgba = '1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922'.split(',');

console.log(rgba[0]);  // "1.000000"
console.log(rgba[1]);  // "0.003922"
console.log(rgba[2]);  // "0.003922"
console.log(rgba[3]);  // "0.003922"
```

To get numbers instead of strings you may use `parseFloat()` or a shortcut `+` trick:

```
var red = parseFloat(rgba[0]);  // 1.000000
var green = +rgba[1];           // 0.003922
```

If your string contains extra data you may either first remove it with `replace()`:

```
var str = 'RGBA:1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922'.replace('RGBA:', ''),
    rgba = str.split(',');
```

or use [regular expression](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Guide/Regular_Expressions) to match numbers:

```
var rgba = 'RGBA:1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922'.match(/\d+\.\d+/g);
>> ["1.000000", "0.003922", "0.003922", "0.003922"]
```

Comment: Might be worth throwing the `parseFloat` bit into your answer - looks like the OP wanted numerics rather than strings

Comment: original string is RGBA:1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922

Comment: @Jamiec Thanks for the catch. I have added it to the answer.

Comment: Another one - slice out the `RGBA` from the start of the string.

Comment: what about the letters RGBA: in the original string

Comment: @Anni: Then do `(string.split(':'))[1].split(',')`

Comment: `'1.000000,0.003922,0.003922,0.003922'.slice(5).split(',');` do a slice first.

Comment: @Jai: Maybe, but probably not better than Xotic's comments in the original: `str.slice(5).split(',').map(Number)`.  This is probably as readable and clean as we're going to see.

Comment: @ScottSauyet `Array.prototype.map` has limited browser support. Moreover `slice(5)` will work only if useless part is 5 characters long and is positioned from index 0.

Comment: `map` has a shim, it is also available in `jQuery`, and why would the string be any different than the OP suggested? And if it was, then those regexs would likely fail too.

Comment: @Xotic750 No, I'm not against your solution, it is brilliant. What I say is that regex has less complications and is more flexible than playing with indices to cut off part of string for such easy operation. Obviously there are many ways to solve the problem.

Comment: Yes, there are many way to solve this problem, it completely depends on the situation. With a simple problem like this, IMO, I prefer K.I.S.S. which for me would mean avoiding any additional complexity added by a RegExp. Sure RegExp is very flexible, no doubt, and this does appear to be a regular pattern. I'm not suggesting that there is anything wrong with this solution either. If counting where to slice is of worry, or the possibility of additional characters in the number components, then you could harden my suggestion like `str.slice(str.indexOf(':') + 1).split(',').map(parseFloat)` :)

Comment: @Xotic750 Or just double `slice`: `str.split(':').pop().split(',').map(parseFloat)` ;)

Comment: Yes, indeed. Another example. :)